# Bootstrapping data on initial page load

Tags: node.js, backbone.js

The code below (`server.js` and `app.js`) is used in a tutorial from Lynda.com for bootstrapping data in a Backbone and Node.js web application.  With the get request to the root folder `app.get('/')` you can see that it's calling `JSON.stringify` on the items that are exported in from a json file (so it's not using a database for the example). The front-end file `app.js` seems to call `app.menuItems.reset({{{ data }}})` on the `data` items that are served up by node.

I have a question about this which isn't explained by the tutorial

1) If node is serving the `data` with the initial `get` request, why would it be necessary to also call `app.menuItems.reset({{{ data }}})`?. Doesn't the `get` request do everything necessary to serve data to the front end?

Please let me know if you need to see more code. I assumed this question could be answered by generic knowledge about bootstrapping without a need to see, for example, app.menuItems.

**server.js**

```
items = require('./data/menu-items');  //static json file

var app = express()
  .use(express.bodyParser())
  .use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index.hbs', {data: JSON.stringify(items)});
});
```

**app.js**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        app.menuItems.reset({{{data}}});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `GET /` to the server does indeed return all the information necessary for the browser to handle the request, but the backbone collection has no clue that the data is in the page until you call `reset` with the data.

Try this:

Change the app.js (which I think is actually your hbs file?) to read:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var myData = {{{data}}};
</script>
```

And you'll see nothing happens.

This is because the backbone part of your application (the `app.js`) is run only on the client. So what that `app.menutItems.reset()` call is doing is telling the browser that when app.js is loaded (so that `app.menuItems` is available), to `reset` the collection with the data from the server.

`reset` is a backbone method that causes the collection to empty any data it might have and load the passed in data as it's own data.  So this will create models out of all the items in `data` and then attach all those models to the collection.

I would guess there is something like `this.listenTo(app.menuItems, 'reset', func...)` or `this.on('reset', func...)` somewhere in your `app.js` code as well which causes the application to actually do something when the data is loaded into the collection.